# Cannot properly generate URL with captured arguments using {% url %} template tag

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-urls

I'm running into an issue with supplying captured URL parameters through template tags. I have a URL dispatch with a captured parameter that hands off to another URL dispatch with `include()` that does not have any captured parameters:

**nodemanager.urls:**
`url(r'^(?P<node_id>\d+)/rank/', include('ranking.urls')),`

**ranking.urls:**
`url(r'^setup$', views.setup, name='setup'),`

I am using `{% url 'setup' node_id=node.id %}` in my template which creates the error:

> TypeError at /stage1/node/5/rank/setup
>
> setup() got an unexpected keyword argument 'node_id'

If I take out the keyword argument and just use: `{% url 'setup' %}`, the landing page fails to load and I get the (predictable) error:

> NoReverseMatch at /stage1/
>
> Reverse for 'setup' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) >tried: ['stage1/node/(?P\d+)/rank/setup$']

I know that I need to supply the parameter for `node_id` to properly reverse the URL. However, the named url "setup" in my ranking app doesn't take any parameters, but the URL that includes it (in the nodemanager app) does.

How would I properly pass the `node_id` keyword argument using a template tag that points to `stage1/node/5/rank/setup`, i.e. something of the form `{% url 'setup' ... %}`. Can I do this?

Let me know if I need to post more context code; I tried to include (what I thought) are the relevant parts.

Comment: and how is the view defined?

Comment: {% url 'ranking:setup' %}

Comment: @rajasimon There is no namespace, so this may not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original error is not due to the URL reversing, but comes when the view is actually called. This is probably because you have not declared it to take a node_id argument. It should be like this:

```
def setup(request, node_id):
    ...
```

Once you've fixed that, the original url tag syntax should work.

Comment: This indeed works!

I tried to read the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/urls/#including-other-urlconfs) again and found "An included URLconf receives any captured parameters from parent URLconfs". Doesn't this go against the Django philosophy of having loosely coupled apps? If I was using a third-party commenting app (for example), would I have to change the source code of its views as well?

Comment: No, because you would only do it with apps that are expecting it. If you don't want to pass a node_id to your included urlconf, then don't include it in the pattern that does the including.